# Ruby version collisions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Heroku no longer accepts the Ruby version that our app is using. So we intended to just use the latest Ruby version and rebuild until we hit this:

`` Make sure that `gem install msgpack -v '0.5.11'` succeeds before bundling. ``

Previous items requesting a `gem install` went without a hitch, but not this one. The failure starts with:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing msgpack:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Then we get a series of errors like this:

```
compiling buffer_class.c
buffer_class.c: In function 'read_until_eof':
buffer_class.c:261:17: warning: passing argument 3 of 'rb_rescue2' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  261 |                 read_until_eof_error, (VALUE)(void*) args,
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 |
      |                 VALUE (*)(VALUE) {aka long long unsigned int (*)(long long unsigned int)}
```

Based on searching Stack Overflow and other places, I concluded that I should simply try `gem install msgpack` and that works just fine. But then the `bundle install` returns to this same complaint.

```
Make sure that `gem install msgpack -v '0.5.11'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I can't seem to find in the bundle settings where we can decide on a more recent version of `msgpack`, so we're stuck in a circle of versions we can't seem to resolve.

Comment: This seems like a dependency issue. You can determine which gem relies on `msgpack -v '0.5.11'` by looking at the Gemfile.lock. Chances are you will need to update that gem so that `msgpack` can also be updated.

Comment: `msgpack 0.5.11` is more than 8 years old. At the time, Ruby 2.2 was up-to-date. You will certainly need to update `msgpack` when you want to run it with an up-to-date version of Ruby.
What version of Ruby and Ruby on Rails did you run previously, and what versions do you try to update to?

Comment: When upgrading Ruby you'll often need to drag your other dependencies forward too, especially for things with compiled extensions.